# Filter matrix rows depending on values in a second matrix

Tags: matlab

Given a 2x3 matrix `x` and a 4x2 matrix `y`, I'd like to use each row of `y` to index into `x`. If the value in `x` is not equal to `-1` I'd like to remove that row from `y`. Here's an example that does what I'd like, except I'd like to do it in a fast, simple way without a loop.

```
x = [1, 2, 3; -1, 2, -1];
y = [1, 1; 1, 3; 2, 1; 2, 3];

for i=size(y,1):-1:1
   if x(y(i,1), y(i,2)) ~= -1
      y(i,:) = [];
   end
end
```

This results in:

```
y =

     2     1
     2     3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A raw approach to what `sub2ind` follows (as used by this pretty nice-looking [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25530257/3293881) posted by Luis) inherently would be this -

```
y = y(x((y(:,2)-1)*size(x,1)+y(:,1))==-1,:)
```

---

## Benchmarking

**Benchmarking Code**

```
N = 5000;
num_runs = 10000;

x = round(rand(N,N).*2)-1;
y = zeros(N,2);
y(:,1) = randi(size(x,1),N,1);
y(:,2) = randi(size(x,2),N,1);

disp('----------------- With sub2ind ')
tic
for k = 1:num_runs
    y1 = y(x(sub2ind(size(x), y(:,1), y(:,2)))==-1,:);
end
toc,clear y1

disp('----------- With raw version of sub2ind ')
tic
for k = 1:num_runs
    y2 = y(x((y(:,2)-1)*size(x,1)+y(:,1))==-1,:);
end
toc
```

**Results**

```
----------------- With sub2ind 
Elapsed time is 4.095730 seconds.
----------- With raw version of sub2ind 
Elapsed time is 2.405532 seconds.
```

Comment: +1 Well done! There was a time when I didn't know about `sub2ind` and I would do it this way. Then I discovered that function and got lazy :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo haha how could you not know about `sub2ind`! :) Well it's fun I guess when we want to avoid function calls for performance and are made to rely on basic mathematical operations, keeps our brains moving :) You have my +1 already!

Comment: In the beginning I didn't know about `sub2ind` or even about linear indexing. I thought linear indexing was some Matlab's bug! ("How does Matlab allow a 2D array to be indexed with _one_ index?") Then I got the logic of it and starting to use it, but doing the conversion manually as in your answer

Comment: @LuisMendo Wow! You have come a long way on that in pretty quick time! Knowing tools of a specific language surely helps, but it all starts with formulating the solution which isn't language specific. Good going btw! :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily vectorized as follows (see [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)):

```
y = y(x(sub2ind(size(x), y(:,1), y(:,2)))==-1,:);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>> x = [1, 2, 3; -1, 2, -1];
>>y = [1, 1; 
    1, 2; 
    1, 3; 
    2, 1;
    2, 2;
    2, 3];
>>row_idx = reshape((x == -1)',1,6);
>>y = y(row_idx,:);
```

I think you didn't include all the index of x in y. I included all of them in y. Have a look..

Generalized version:

```
>> x = [1, 2, 3; -1, 2, -1];
>>y = [1, 1; 
    1, 2; 
    1, 3; 
    2, 1;
    2, 2;
    2, 3];
>>row_idx = reshape((x == -1)',1,size(x,1)*size(x,2));
>>y = y(row_idx,:);
```

Comment: Thanks @lakesh, missing out some of the indices was deliberate. I should have mentioned that in the question, sorry.

Comment: If you could make a generalized version of it, I would be happy to include that into benchmarking.

Comment: I was unable to run for these inputs - `N = 5, x = round(rand(N,N).*2)-1, y = randi(size(x,1),N,2)`