# Vectorising row lookup

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, vectorization

I have a matrix of 1000 rows x 500 columns stored in `a`. I also have a vector of 1000 integers `l` in the range between `1` and `500`. I want to compute sum of `a(i,l(i))` for all `i`. Can this be done quickly without using for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the linear indices of the elements whose elements are to be summed up and then find the scalar sum value. So, this should do it pretty efficiently -

```
nrows = size(a,1) %// number of rows in input matrix a
idx = (l(:)-1)*nrows + [1:nrows]' %//'# linear indices of elements to be summed up
                                        %// OR idx = sub2ind(size(a),[1:nrows]',l(:))
sumval = sum(a(idx)) %// index into a and get the sum value
```

Comment: Nice!  I suspect this is faster than `sub2ind`. +1.

Comment: Hey @rayryeng!:) Yup, [it has to be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528685/filter-matrix-rows-depending-on-values-in-a-second-matrix/25530905#25530905).

Comment: Nice :) I've actually used this in place of `sub2ind` for a lot of the code I wrote in the past... I just forgot about it up to this point.

Answer (score 2):

Another method I can suggest is to create a [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix that is `logical` where all values are `true` such that they are located at the row locations from 1 to `N` where `N` is the amount of rows and the column locations directly from using the `l` vector.  You would then use this `logical` matrix to index into your matrix `a` then sum up all of the entries.  In other words:

```
s = sparse(1:size(a,1), l, true);
sumval = sum(a(s));
```

`size(a,1)` would be `N` in our case, as this computes the total number of rows.  I just decided to place it inside the `sparse` call to make the code compact.

Comment: Can you index a numeric array with sparse array of indices?

Comment: @Divakar - Blah.  I meant to change the final input parameter to `true`.  Did that on my end, but forgot to change my post.  Thanks for spotting the typo!  You can see I meant to set it to `true` in my description, but forgot to set it in my code.

Comment: @Divakar - Cheers :) Thanks for spotting my typo!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had a hard time to decide which of the two answers has been more helpfull.