# Replace specific matrix position with array value without using for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

can I know how can I replace values in specific matrix position without using for loop in MATLAB? I initialize matrix `a` that I would like to replace its value on specified row and column for each `no`. This has to be done a few time within `num` for loop. The `num` for loop is important here because I would want the update the value in the original code.

The real code is more complicated, I am simplifying the code for this question.

**I have the code as follow:**

```
a = zeros(2,10,15);



for num = 1:10

    b = [2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2]; 
    c = [8.0268 5.5218 2.9893 5.7105 7.5969 7.5825 7.0740 4.6471 ...
    6.3481 14.7424 13.5594 10.6562 7.3160 -4.4648 30.6280];

    d = [1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 6 1 1];

    for no = 1:15
        a(b(no),d(no),no) = c(1,no,:)
    end

end
```

**A sample output for, say no 13 is as follows:**

```
a(:,:,13) =

  Columns 1 through 8

         0         0         0         0         0      7.3160       0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0

  Columns 9 through 10

         0         0
         0         0
```

Thank you so much for any help I could get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done using `sub2ind`, which casts the subs to a linear index.
Following your vague variable names, it would look like this (omitting the useless loop over `num`):

```
a = zeros(2,10,15);
b = [2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2]; 
d = [1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 6 1 1];
c = [8.0268 5.5218 2.9893 5.7105 7.5969 7.5825 7.0740 4.6471 ...
6.3481 14.7424 13.5594 10.6562 7.3160 -4.4648 30.6280];

% // we vectorize the loop over no:
no = 1:15;
a(sub2ind(size(a), b, d, no)) = c;
```

Comment: @loss you're welcome. As Divakar pointed out: for raw speed you can strip down ``sub2ind`` to the only compute the linear indices for the 3-dimensional case directly. Doesn't get more readable though ;-). Also depending on what really happens within the ``num`` loop, you can probably extract some code out of that loop.

Comment: Noted @Nras. I will try all the codes and see which is suitable inside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the `sub2ind` based approach as suggested in [Nras's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28942885/3293881), you can use a `"raw version" of sub2ind` to reduce a function call if performance is very critical. The related benchmarks comparing `sub2ind` and it's raw version is listed in [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25530905/3293881). Here's the implementation to solve your case -

```
no = 1:15
a = zeros(2,10,15);
[m,n,r] = size(a)
a((no-1)*m*n + (d-1)*m + b) = c
```

---

Also for pre-allocation, you can use a much faster approach as listed in [`Undocumented MATLAB blog post on Preallocation performance`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance) with -

```
a(2,10,15) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `sub2ind` is your friend here:

```
a = zeros(2,10,15);

x = [2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2];
y = [1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 6 1 1];
z = 1:15;

dat = [8.0268 5.5218 2.9893 5.7105 7.5969 7.5825 7.0740 4.6471 ...
    6.3481 14.7424 13.5594 10.6562 7.3160 -4.4648 30.6280];

inds = sub2ind(size(a), x, y, z);

a(inds) = dat;
```

Answer (score 1):

Matlab provides a function 'sub2ind' may do what you expected.

with variable as the same you posted:

```
idx = sub2ind(size(a),b,d,[1:15]); % return the index of row a column b and page [1:15]
a(idx) = c;
```