# MATLAB: Use a single row vector to specify which row element of a multiple row matrix to select

Tags: matlab, vector, initialization, rows

Given an mxn matrix e.g.

```
 M= [ 10 20 30 40; 11 12 13 14; 19 18 17 16];
```

and a 1xn 'selector'

```
 S = [1 2 3 1];
```

where all elements of S are in the range 1..m, I want the output vector O with size 1xn s.t. O[1, i] = M[ S[i], i]. In this example

```
O = [10 12 17 40];
```

Clearly I can do this using a loop. Is there a way to vectorize it which is more cost effective than a loop assuming that m and n are in the hundreds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`sub2ind`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html). So the desired output could be achieved with -

```
O = M(sub2ind(size(M),S,1:numel(S)))
```

Or for performance, you can use a *raw version* of `sub2ind` -

```
O = M([0:numel(S)-1]*size(M,1) + S)
```

Comment: @DaveDurbin The performance boost would be `~2x` with it. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25530905/3293881)'s some related benchmarks.