# Assignment element of matrix without for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, vectorization, linear-programming

I'm trying to build a constraint matrix that I'm going to use with [`linprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html), and I'm struggling to build it efficiently without using for loops. Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
A = zeros(3, 3); % Constraint matrix
i = [1 3]; % row indexes
j = [1 2 ; 1 3]; % column indexes
x = [1 2 ; 3 4]; % values to assign
```

Expected result after assignment:

```
A = [1 2 0 ; 0 0 0 ; 3 0 4]
```

I want to perform the following operations:

```
A(i(1), j(1,:)) = x(1,:)
A(i(2), j(2,:)) = x(2,:)
```

For now, I'm using a for loop:

```
for k=1:length(i)
    A(i(k), j(k,:)) = x(k,:);
end
```

Is there any better way to do this for any `i` and `j`? I could use a for loop everywhere, but the number of constraint depends on the number of variables, so my code gets filled with for-loops. What's the standard way of defining the constraint matrix to use with `linprog`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One [`vectorized`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) approach with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
A(bsxfun(@plus,ii(:),(jj-1)*size(A,1))) = x
```

You need the `expansion` with `bsxfun` as the number of row indices don't match up with the number of column indices.

Also, please note that I have replaced the variable names `i` with `ii` and `j` with `jj` as `i` and `j` are also used with complex numbers, as that might cause some *conflict* otherwise.

Sample run -

```
>> ii(:)    %// Row indices
ans =
     1
     3
>> jj       %// Column indices
jj =
     1     2     4
     1     3     5
>> x        %// Values to assign
x =
     1     2     6
     3     4     8
>> A        %// Output
A =
     1     2     0     6     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     3     0     4     0     8
```

---

It has two benefits:

1. Avoiding the call to `sub2ind` with a *raw-version* of it, for being [`more efficient with runtime`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528685/filter-matrix-rows-depending-on-values-in-a-second-matrix/25530905#25530905).
2. The expansion being done internally without using any loop or `repmat` saves looping or another function call respectively.

Comment: Very clever approach to get the right indices (Y) took this long to understand :D

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for teach me a new trick! Though I still don't know where you come up with these shamanistic invocations to bsxfun :P

Comment: @brodroll Basically, you keep on using it to every god-damn problem you get on SO and it gets to you!! :)

Comment: +1 because your solution works out of the box and for the edits explaining the (to me) cryptic code. I don`t get why you have a 3x5 matrix as outcome

Comment: @brodroll The inputs I am using are different (includes more input elements than in the original problem) and in it `jj` goes to `5`, so `A` must have 5 columns.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is the [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) function. Here's how you would improve your matrix creations:

```
>> indx = sub2ind(size(A),[1 3 1 3]',j(:))
indx =

   1
   3
   4
   9

>> A(indx)=x(:)
A =

   1   2   0
   0   0   0
   3   0   4
```

Note that you would have to tweak your *i* definition a little bit so *i* and *j* have the same number of elements.

Comment: Good one for octave! Love that automatic broadcasting in it.

Comment: I just noticed that you are not actually using broadcasting in it. I think OP meant that his/her code is working as with that loopy code even with unequal number of elements in `i` and `j` it works, but just wanted to remove the loop?

Comment: @Divakar That is what I understood. The loopy code is working but is cumbersome to repeat throughout the script and he/she wanted to find a better/more compact way to populate the matrices. Sorry about the broadcasting feature! Indeed I was not using it

Comment: How about `indx = (j-1)*size(A,1) + i(:)`? That should get the broadcasting going? And then `A(indx)=x`.

Comment: Sweet, that would also work! Nice way to create the indexes. You would just have to use transpose *i* first, to get the right answer. Basically you could bypass sub2ind altogether and avoid expanding *i* (as I did)!

Comment: Exactly, that's what I did too! I just let the bsxfun take care of the broadcasting with MATLAB.

Comment: octave:1> (j-1)*size(A,1)+i'
warning: operator +: automatic broadcasting operation applied.
Cool feature! That makes 2 tricks learned for 1 question. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, making use of [`sparse`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html):

```
A = full(sparse(repmat(ii,size(jj,1),1).', jj ,x));
```

I'm using `ii` and `jj` as variable names instead of `i` and `j`, as in [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29879998/2586922).

Comment: Yeah,  I had the hunch you would come up with sparse!

Comment: @Divakar Only because you used up `bsxfun` :-P