# Scan each column without for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization

```
I = [2 1];
A = [7 11
     8 17];
```

How can I pick the right value in A without `for` loop? `I` is a vector of indices for each column in `A`. That is `I(1) is 8` and `I(2) = 11`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to generate linear indices based on the right row and column coordinates, then use these to index into `A`.  In this case, `I` chooses the right row and you want to choose only one element for each column from the first up to the last:

```
ind = sub2ind(size(A), I, 1:numel(I));
out = A(ind);
```

## Example

```
>> I = [2 1];
>> A = [7 11
        8 17];
>> ind = sub2ind(size(A), I, 1:numel(I));
>> out = A(ind);
>> out

out =

     8    11
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was hoping to find.

Comment: @bisherbas My pleasure.  Good luck!

Comment: @bisherbas A possibly faster alternative would be `out = A((0:size(A,1):numel(A)-1)+I)`. It does the same as `sub2ind`, but avoids some overhead

Comment: @bisherbas Luis's suggestion has the related benchmarks here, if you are interested - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25530905/3293881