# MATLAB-Get a sub-matrix by a matrix of index

Tags: matlab

everybody

Suppose I have a matrix A

```
A = [2 3 7; 1 5 4; 3 9 6]
```

and a matrix B

```
B = [2 1 3]
```

I want to get a matrix C from A by index of B, but not use a loop
for example,

```
C = [1 3 6]
or C = [A(B(1)) A(B(2)) A(B(3))]
```

Not use "for" loop
Help me, please? 
Thanks

Comment: Given `B` where each element's position corresponds to the column you want to examine in `A`, you want to pull out the rows governed by each of the corresponding elements in `B`.  That has already been solved.  Check the duplicate.

Comment: @DennisKlopfer: No, it's just a result I want to get, not a true code,

Comment: @rayryeng: I'm searching in your question list to get the solution. Could you give me the link of the duplicate, please?

Comment: It's at the top of this page. You can't miss it. See the yellow bar with text? Click there.

Comment: @rayryeng: thanks, I found it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715723/scan-each-column-without-for-loop-in-matlab?lq=1